# A freeware tool to create heightmaps

Tags: gratis, 3d, game-development

I would like to create a heightmap with an editor. I need two images as result:

- Grayscale heightmap (24bit BMP or PNG if possible)
- The texture

All the editors I've found, supports a special format, or the result is a 3D object (.obj or .dae or something else)

But all I need is just a heightmap, and the texture. I want to generate a mesh from the grayscale heightmap, and apply the texture on it.

Comment: Which ones have you tried? I don't want to give answers for products that don't meet your requirements.

Comment: What do you mean by "Just a heightmap"? Something like that does not exist. A height map must have a file format. Which file format would you like?

Comment: What is "my program"? If we shall provide an answer that is compatible with your program, we should at least know the name of it.

Comment: I'm working on a game, which generates a mesh from a heightmap, and applies a texture on it.

Comment: The heightmap is usually a grayscale texture where dark means low, white means high: http://i.imgur.com/lr8MfQW.jpg

Comment: Ok, that's a starting point. RGB, 24bit, uncompressed, PNG? Or greyscale 8 bits, compressed TIF?

Comment: 24bit BMP or PNG if possible

Comment: Sorry if it is still unclear to me: so you basically need a 3D editor to model the height map? And you will also paint the texture yourself? This will be an enormous effort. Typically you find the texture somewhere (e.g. on [cgtextures](http://www.textures.com/)) and then create a height map from the texture using tools.

Comment: I would like to edit the heightmap in the editor, and paint the imported textures on it.

Comment: @IterAtor You may find it beneficial to update your question with some of the details you have provided in the comments.